# Rake команда не найдена, создание базы данных

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

```
Command 'rake' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install rake

root@Sun:/media/playground#
```

хочу создать базу данных, но появляется ошибка

Comment: В ответ на что вы получаете эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно установить данную утилиту.
В терминале введите комманду

```
sudo apt install rake
```

Введите свой пароль и следуйте инструкциям

Comment: Далее появилась такая ошибка 

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Кажется, вы делаете что-то не то. У вас какая задача, поднять Rails на машине? Если да, тогда дополнительно rake ставить не нужно, он входит в рельсы. Вам нужно запустить его из окружения рельс: зайти в директорию приложения, выполнить там `bundle install`, а затем `bundle exec rake db:setup` или `bundle exec rails db:setup` в зависимости от версии Rails, но сейчас можете использовать любую команду. И было здорово немного подробнее рассказать здесь о том, чего пытаетесь достичь и какие шаги уже выполнили, чтобы не гадать.